# Show alter table changes in Django model

Tags: php, django, database, django-models

I have a common database which is accessed by Django app and php project. I added some columns to a table to that database from my php side. So my question is how can I see the changes made in my database reflect in the models.py file in Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Manasvi you can run `python manage.py inspectdb > sample_model.py` command inside your django project which will generate '**sample_model.py**' file from where you can copy from your required model's code and replace it in your main **models.py** file.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is an `inspectdb` tool that can generate models from an existing database. You could try running this in a new project, and comparing the auto generated models to your existing models.

However, Django does not have a tool to update models based on the current state of the databases. If you change the database, it's up to you to update the models, and create and fake any migrations unless the models are unmanaged by Django.